# Apache funciona mas php não funciona

Tags: php, linux

Foi instalado o apache em um `centos 7` e o serviço está ativo e o php também foi instalado, mas sempre que jogo no nagevador o php não executa, apenas mostra o código php.

ao verificar a versão com o comando `php -v` me mostra

```
PHP 7.2.7 (cli) (built: Jun 20 2018 08:21:26) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
```

E o servidor http está ativo.

Estou usando Centos 7

Comment: Quando tu executa algum projeto local aparece algum erro ?

Comment: Não aparece erro. Nem o `info.php` funciona. Mostra o código no navegador

Comment: É só você instalar o módulo do PHP do apache.
Roda esse comando no terminal. sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php7